# Why were Series variables of ModelBuilder removed at ArcGIS 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, batch

I've read a [number of posts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/36891) regarding the sequential batch processing of a model in ArcGIS.  In particular [this one](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/15090), because I'm having the exact same issue.

Recently, I found an old [9.3 help page](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/Gp_ToolRef/automating_your_work_with_models/an_overview_of_model_iteration.htm) that shows that ArcGIS at one time supported a type of value called a series which is missing from the current 10.2 dialogue in model builder.

It appears that what I need to achieve my sequential processing of multiple input parameters for my model is what was once called a "series value" in 9.3.

I'm just wondering if anyone knows what happened to this and if there is some way to achieve the same thing in 10.2?

It's hard to believe that Esri would take functionality out of more recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall ever having much joy when trying to use Series variables in ArcGIS Desktop 9.3 so I did not worry when I saw it gone and Iterators introduced at ArcGIS 10.0.

I any event, I think the issue you are having may be related to [**NIM053898**](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/TklNMDUzODk4) which is currently treated by Esri as a Known Limit.

However, I think it should be addressed with priority because being able to use ModelBuilder to create a tool that can simply be run in Batch is very appealing.

At the moment my favoured workaround to meet batch geoprocessing requirements, is to avoid the ModelBuilder and Batch Grid combination, and use ArcPy instead.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me!  I'll be looking forward to the issue being corrected since as of now ArcPy is a bit out of my wheelhouse.